# How to use FloatRangeSlider as range of X axis of a plot

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am trying to make an interactive plot using ipywidgets.
The final goal of the plot is to have a slider which will select the range of x-axis thus, automatically update the y-axis.
My main issue is to understand the update function in order to make the update of the range slider.
**The final Plot from the example bellow should show only the xaxis = 4 to 10 and yaxis = 0 to 1000**.
[image]

The code I have is the following:

```
from ipywidgets.widgets import FloatRangeSlider
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
xData = np.linspace(0,15)
yData = xData**3

# Create slider
rangeX = FloatRangeSlider( 
    min=min(xData), max=max(xData), step=0.1, 
    description='Time (hours)'
)
### The issue is to update ###
def update(change):
    line.set_ydata(change*yData)
    fig.canvas.draw()

%matplotlib notebook
 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(xData, yData)
ax.grid(True)
## call observe to update the plot
rangeX.observe(update, 'value')
```

Comment: Start by printing your `change` object in your `update` function. You should be able to see where to extract the left and right edges of your chart from the widget values.